# Play a 2nd youtube video after first one has finished playing

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have embedded youtube videos on my site. After the embedded video has finished playing I would like to immediately autoplay another youtube video.
How could I do that?

Comment: It is better to regard the code by which you embedded the two videos.

Comment: I'm just using the standard <iframe ..> embed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initialize your youtube player add the onStateChange Event.  Then see what the event was and if it was a PlayerState.Ended then you load the next video.  something like this

```
    this.player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: pxHeight,
      width: pxWidth,
      playerVars: {
                                'rel': 0,
                                'controls': 0,
                                'fs':0
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
        'onError': onError
      }
    });

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        LOG("Youtube Playing");
    } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
        LOG(">>>Youtube Ended");
        this.player.loadVideoById(ID, 0, "default");
    } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PAUSED) {
        LOG("Youtube Paused");
    } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.BUFFERING) {
        LOG("Youtube Buffering");
    } else if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.CUED) {
        LOG("Youtube Cued");
    }
  }
```